# Why does my header and navigation act differently on different pages with same CSS

Tags: html, css, header

Why does my header and navigation act differently on different pages?
Im trying to make another page that has the same navigation and header as the main page but for some reason it acts differently on the second page I'm trying to make even though its using the same CSS.

PAGE ONE

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Amanda Farrington</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>


    <div id="header">
        <div id="leftHeader">
        <img src="assets/logo2.jpg" alt="Logo" style="width:65px;height:65px">
        <h1>Amanda Farrington</h1>
    </div>
        <div id="nav">

      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#workJump">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="mentally.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div id="hero">
        <div id="heroImage">
        <img src="assets/trees.jpg" alt="trees" style="width:100%;height:10%">
        </div>

        <div id="overlay">
        <h2>Amanda Farrington</h2>
        <h3>Graphic Artist | Web Designer</h3>
        </div>
    </div>


<a name="workJump"></a>

    <div id="work">
        <div id="label">
        <h4>Work</h4>
        </div>
    <div id="leftColumn">
        <div id= "p2article">
        <img src="assets/trees.jpg" alt="trees" style="width:100%;height:100%">
        <div id= "articleinfo2">
        <div id= "articleText2">
        <span class="title3">Beyond the Bricks 2-2</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id= "p2article">
        <img src="assets/trees.jpg" alt="trees" style="width:100%;height:100%">
        <div id= "articleinfo2">
        <div id= "articleText2">
        <span class="title3">Beyond the Bricks 2-2</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id= "p2article">
        <img src="assets/trees.jpg" alt="trees" style="width:100%;height:100%">
        <div id= "articleinfo2">
        <div id= "articleText2">
        <span class="title3">Beyond the Bricks 2-2</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

                <div id= "p2article">
        <img src="assets/trees.jpg" alt="trees" style="width:100%;height:100%">
        <div id= "articleinfo2">
        <div id= "articleText2">
        <span class="title3">Beyond the Bricks 2-2</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="rightColumn">
        <div id= "p2article2">
        <img src="assets/trees.jpg" alt="trees" style="width:100%;height:100%">
        <div id= "articleinfo2">
        <div id= "articleText2">
        <span class="title3">Beyond the Bricks 2-2</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id= "p2article2">
        <img src="assets/trees.jpg" alt="trees" style="width:100%;height:100%">
        <div id= "articleinfo2">
        <div id= "articleText2">
        <span class="title3">Beyond the Bricks 2-2</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

                <div id= "p2article2">
        <img src="assets/trees.jpg" alt="trees" style="width:100%;height:100%">
        <div id= "articleinfo2">
        <div id= "articleText2">
        <span class="title3">Beyond the Bricks 2-2</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

                <div id= "p2article2">
        <img src="assets/trees.jpg" alt="trees" style="width:100%;height:100%">
        <div id= "articleinfo2">
        <div id= "articleText2">
        <span class="title3">Beyond the Bricks 2-2</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

PAGE TWO

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Amanda Farrington</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>


    <div id="header">
        <div id="leftHeader">
        <img src="assets/logo2.jpg" alt="Logo" style="width:65px;height:65px">
        <h1>Amanda Farrington</h1>
    </div>
        <div id="nav">

      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="tips.html">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="mentally.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div id="hero2">
        <h6>Project Type</h6>
        <h5>Project Title</h5>
    </div>


    <div id="workImage">
        <img src="assets/trees.jpg" alt="Logo" style="width:100%;height:100%">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;

}

/*----------header styles-------------*/
#header {
  color: #D7DADB;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size : 15px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 3em;
  position: relative;
  height: 15%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


#header img
{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 3em;
}

h1{
width: 9em;
float: left;
padding-left: 0.5em;
color: #45CCCC;
padding-bottom: 1px;
}

#nav {
  width: 40%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align: right;
  color: red;
  font-size:20px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 2em;

}

#nav ul {
  padding: 1px;
}

#nav li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 38px;
}

#nav li a {
  color: #2C3E50;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li a:hover {
  color: #45CCCC;
}

/*----------hero image styles-------------*/
#hero{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30em;
    position: relative;
}

#heroImage
{
    top: 9%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

#overlay{
    width: 34em;
    top: 70%;
    margin-left: 30%;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    clear: left;

}

h2{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 60px;
    float: center;
    color: white;
    opacity: 1.0;

    text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000000;
    text-align: center;
}

h3{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    opacity: 1.0;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #000000;
    text-align: center;

}

/*----------work main styles-------------*/
#leftColumn
{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 70em;
}

#rightColumn
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 70em;
    float: right;
}

#label{
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    top: 10em;
}
#work{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10em;
    position: relative;
    top: 8em;
}

h4{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #45CCCC;
    opacity: 1.0;
    text-align: center;
}


#p2article2
{
  width: 70%;
  height:20em;
  float: center;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 10em;
  margin-top: 5em;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  background: purple;
}

#p2article
{
  width: 70%;
  height:20em;
  float: center;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 10em;
  margin-top: 5em;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  background: purple;
}

#articleinfo2
{
  width:100%;
  height:10em;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5em;


}

#articleText2{
  width: 90%;
  height:70%;
  margin: 5%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;


}


/*----------work page styles-------------*/
#hero2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10em;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    top: 10em;
}

#workImage
{
    top: 9%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: static;

}

h5{

    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #45CCCC;
    float: left;

}

h6{

    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #45CCCC;
    float: left;

}
```

Comment: Please define "acting differently"...

Comment: It acts the way I want it to on the main page, but when i made a new page with the heading, half of it is cut off at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Tested a bit and it seems to be caused by not clearing `float`, removing the negative top margin from `#header` and then adding this last line of CSS should solve it :

```
#overlay {
width: 100%;
height: 30em;
position: relative;
clear: left;
}
```

You may want to do the same with `#work` even though it doesn't seem to be influencing the layout.

If I may add - not all the floats would be necessary. Removing the one on `#header` for example seems to have no impact. I guess the less it's used, the better. And you could get rid of the horizontal scrollbar with this bit of code if you like :

```
#header {
color: #D7DADB;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
font-size : 15px;
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
padding-left: 3em;
position: relative;
height: 15%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: That helped take care of all the navigation issues but now my image in "heroImage" moved and theres a white apace below the header. How would i fix that issue?

Comment: I see what you mean, probably clearing the float on `#overlay` is a better idea then. The image (I'm just seeing the fallback text for it in my test though) seems to stay in place that way. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Okay, so i deleted the negative top margin and added clear: left; to #overlay but now the image is overlapping the header.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Could you maybe give me a link to the image or let me know it's dimensions? I cannot extract that from the code alone...

Comment: The dimensions are 800 × 333. I also updated my question with the code I currently have so you can see what I'm looking at.

Comment: I think I get it... it's a rather large background image. Pasted a random one in the code to test and I can see it overlappimg. Giving `#heroImage` the style `z-index: -1` should do the trick there. If more quirks show up, could you maybe make a reduced case on Codepen or a fiddle? It's a bit hard to see what's happening when making changes without the code fully showing (images and all). Or a live link to your project...

Comment: Changing the z- index just changes the order it was overlapping in, i want to move all the content down so theres no overlapping at all. What is a reduced case on Codepen or a fiddle?

Comment: They are sites where the code can be pasted to get a live example. Reduced really only means showing the parts that would be relevant to the issue. https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codepen.io ("New Pen" at the top) It makes it easier to do some changes on the fly and show what a current issue might be.

Comment: Great, you're welcome of course. I wouldn't mind an upvote on the answer if it was helpful naturally. ;-)

Comment: It says it requires 15 reputation, i just joined today. Ill definitely up vote it when i build my reputation!

Comment: Okay, didn't realise that. Lol. I'd help out anyway, no doubt. But thanks in any case!